# Problema con react-native 0.56 al instalar la aplicación en Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, babel

Estoy haciendo uso de react-native-firebase, en iOS no tuve problema alguno al integrar la librería, sin embargo, en Android me esta generando problemas, intente actualizar la versión de react-native a las 0.56, guiandome de las soluciones indexadas en google, este es el error que obtengo, parece ser un problema con babel. Agradezco de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi package.json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

build.gradle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app/build.gradle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No deberías tener problemas con la versión de react-native recuerda que la instalación de ios y android van por separado. te recomiendo que corras de nuevo tu `react-native run-ios` y si todo sigue bien por el lado de ios abre tu **Android Studio** ya que es mejor a la hora de instalar estos componentes revisar si tienes posibles errores desde la parte nativa te recomiendo esta pagina para que revises tu instalación en **Android** y sigas los pasos mencionados es esta: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/android

aún desconosco el uso que le vas a dar a firebase en tu App pero en esa página web tienes la documentación de todos los módulos como en mi caso fue el de **Auth y RealTime Database**. Saludos :V